# Why cannot I not connect to my server when using a sub-domain?

Tags: python, server, dns, web-hosting, self-hosting

I'm trying to host content on `crypto.hazim.dev`. I went ahead and registered the domain `hazim.dev` , and updated the DNS records for `hazim.dev` to point to my server's IP address. I ran :

```
python3 -m http.server --bind 0.0.0.0 80
```

on the server and I managed to connect without a problem. I then deleted the DNS record for `hazim.dev` and replaced it with `crypto.hazim.dev` still pointing to the same IP address. I waited a day for it to propagate. When I ran:

```
nslookup crypto.hazim.dev
```

It shows the correct IP address, but when I put `crypto.hazim.dev` into my URL bar I get:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Based on the error it seems like it's managing to find a DNS record for the URL but it's not connecting. If I put in the IP address directly into my web browser's URL bar it connects fine.

Comment: That may be a configuration problem in Apache server which may reply hazim.dev

Comment: I add you seems to be running apache not python3 http server. Try to stp apache server before. You can also try start python server with port 8080.

Comment: Your DNS is OK. The problem is in the Apache server configuration. Looks that `ServerName` directive is missed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no DNS problem in your configuration, see DNSViz results: https://dnsviz.net/d/crypto.hazim.dev/YYbT5A/dnssec/

You probably forgot another important point, specific to `.dev` TLD and all other Google ones: the TLD is in HSTS preloading list which means browsers will ONLY connect to port 443 aka HTTPS, they will never do HTTP, which you intend by binding to port 80.

When you register your domain, your registrar should have displayed a notice to you explaining that your domain will only work with an "SSL certificate" (sic). Of course that applies to all names inside your zone, not just the apex.

See this text on https://get.dev/:

> Your security is our priority. The .dev top-level domain is included on the HSTS preload list, making HTTPS required on all connections to .dev websites and pages without needing individual HSTS registration or configuration. Security is built in.

So you need to generate a certificate and listen on port 443.